# jquery showing div but not hiding it afterwards

Tags: jquery

Below is my div:

```
<div id="popup" onClick="hidePopup" style="display:none; position: absolute; 
top: 30px; 
left: 50%; margin-left: -85px; height: 185px; width: 170px; background-color:grey; 
z-index:99; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;">Message</div>'
```

here are my two functions:

```
   function popup(){
     $('#popup').show();
    }
    function hidePopup(){
     $('#popup').hide();
    }
```

Function popup works fine and hows the above div. but when I click on the abive div, hidePopup fails to hide the div. Is there a simple error in my code or is there some other reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: does it happen when the .show() function is already in progress? I think it can be timing problem, try checking for `:animater` pseudo class, when executing hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="popup" onClick="hidePopup();" style="display:none; position: absolute;
```

instead of

```
<div id="popup" onClick="hidePopup;" style="display:none; position: absolute;
```

note these brackets **()**

Answer (score 1):

change `onClick="hidePopup"` to `onClick="hidePopup()"`

Answer (score 1):

Why not re-write it as

`<div id="popup">Message</div>` with this jQuery:

```
$("#popup").click(function() {
   $(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the toggle function like this:

```
function popup(){
 $('#popup').toggle();
}
```

This way you don't have to have different functions to show and hid.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing round brackets after your onclick event. The following code will work:

```
<div id="popup" onClick="hidePopup()" style="display:none; position: absolute; 
top: 30px; 
left: 50%; margin-left: -85px; height: 185px; width: 170px; background-color:grey; 
z-index:99; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;">Message</div>
```

**hidePopup()** being the change

Answer (score 0):

i can't find any error in your code. Where is the part of your code that calls show() ?

Try adding parenthesis () after onClick="hidePopup" onClick="hidePopup()"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more detail in your `onClick`, try this:

```
<div id="popup" onClick="hidePopup();" style="display:none; position: absolute; 
top: 30px; 
left: 50%; margin-left: -85px; height: 185px; width: 170px; background-color:grey; 
z-index:99; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;">Message</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the onclick and in your document.ready function do

```
$("#popup").click(function(){
 $(this).toggle();
```

}

This will change from hidden to visible or visible to hidden depending on what the element is currently.